# High memory usage when resolving @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory

I am profiling my webapp (using Spring + Hibernate) and have found out that in the point where a service method has to be resolved as transactional, I get huge amounts of memory being used.

This is the call to the service method from the Controller:

```
User e = userService.getUser();
```

And this is the said method in the Service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getUser(Long id) throws GenericDataBaseException, InstanceNotFoundException {
        User e = userDao.findById(id);
        return e;
    }
```

By debugging my application, I put a breakpoint right in the method call (first code snippet), and another one on the first line of getUser(). Now only this injection and aspect resolving of the @Transactional annotation fires 30 mb of memory usage. Here's a screencap of VisualVM:

[image]

The bump you see was provoked by this call. Now if a single controller method has several calls to transactional service methods, this accumulates to bumps of around 100MB of memory usage. This can be Garbage Collected so it's not a memory leak, but I am curious as to what might be causing this issue, and whether it's normal behaviour. This only happens the first time a transactional method is called. Succesive calls cause almost no memory usage.

EDIT: Here's a heap dump after the memory bump:
[image]

EDIT2: Here's another screencap with a lot of memory being eaten by Finalizer objects from some ZipFileInflaterInputStream (which I don't use!)
[image]

Comment: Take a heap dump to see what's in memory at that time.

Comment: I have edited my original post with a heap dump after the memory usage dump

Comment: I have found out that this happens only with LocalSessionFactoryBean as transaction Manager. Using another transaction manager does not cause this memory bump, I am guessin this has to do with hibernate SessionFactory using too much memory.

Comment: Just added another screencap of my heap dump with a lot of memory being eaten by some ZipFileInputStream objects!

Comment: It's very difficult for us to remotely analyse this, you're kind of on your own. You can use tools like http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to help. If I was you, I'd take a heap dump before, and after, then try and compare them, or use eclipse mat to try and find some hotspots. Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment, I don't have enough rep, but at a guess, I'd say that the ZipFileInputStream is being created by Hibernate to process, uncompress and create the object(s) being sent back out of the database with a Finalizer instance being created for each field (maybe). I'm guessing that this file would be compressed for the transfer, although the fact that it doesn't happen if you don't use a LocalSessionFactory is interesting. I have no evidence for this other than a gut feeling, but it may lead somewhere.

Comment: That sounds possible, I had no idea Hibernate used ZipFileInputStreams for that. Anyway it just seems that it's accumulating too many of these Finalizer instances, seems to me it might be having some trouble finalizing objects. Question is why? There does not seem to be any info on the net about this.

Comment: Hahaha I have no idea what Hibernate uses them for, its just a wild guess. Are you doing any work with lazily loaded collection objects? Does your user object contain an ArrayList or HashMap or something?